# Nokia HERE maps: Get a list of all places-categories

Tags: here-api

I need a list of all `Categories` used by places in nokia HERE maps.

From the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics/categories.html#categories) I have found these,

```
eat-drink,
going-out,
sights-museums,
transport,
accommodation,
shopping,
leisure-outdoor,
administrative-areas-buildings,
natural-geographical
```

But the places returned by [RESTful api](http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=52.5310,13.3848&app_id=bH5geeDMrFYJLx6jDoHN&app_code=GhubOTUE70HSzryrNaF7-A) have much more categories, some of the Categories I found are these,
`restaurant, theatre-music-culture, cinema, shop, shopping, accommodation, sights-museums, transport, museum, 
landmark-attraction, snacks-fast-food, hotel, food-drink, kiosk-convenience-store, eat-drink, hostel, recreation, 
bar-pub, hardware-house-garden-shop, coffee-tea, clothing-accessories-shop, bookshop, dance-night-club, department-store, 
going-out, leisure-outdoor, administrative-areas-buildings, natural-geographical`
which are not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Where do I get a list of all such categories?

Comment: Here maps Places API and Venue maps API provide categories : For venue maps API categories refer [this link](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/venue-maps/topics/resource-categories.html) Here is the right link to Places API categories in Here documentation (The link given by OP is not valid anymore) : [Here Maps Places API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics/categories.html#categories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of categories can be obtained using the `categories` endpoint.

Example:
[http://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places...](http://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places?at=37.7851,-122.4047&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&accept=application/json)

See the [Places API reference](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places) - particularly the **resources** section for more details. You should also bear in mind the following:

> The category graph may change at any point in the future and may be
>   different depending on the location of the request.  Only the subset of
>   **fixed** categories can be used as filters. These categories are guaranteed
>   not to be removed in future releases. At the moment, the
>   following **fixed** categories are defined:
>
> - eat-drink
> - going-out
> - sights-museums
> - transport
> - accommodation
> - shopping
> - leisure-outdoor
> - administrative-areas-buildings
> - natural-geographical

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for! Thanks. Can you help me with this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842226/nokia-here-maps-how-to-get-the-mczoom-and-mcpan-components

Answer (score 2):

These are the drones you're looking for:

eat-drink:

- restaurant
- snacks-fast-food
- bar-pub
- coffee-tea

  - coffee
  - tea

going-out:

- dance-night-club
- cinema
- theatre-music-culture
- casino

sights-museums:

- landmark-attraction
- museum
- religious-place

transport:

- airport
- railway-station
- public-transport
- ferry-terminal
- taxi-stand

accommodation:

- hotel
- motel
- hostel
- camping

shopping:

- kiosk-convenience-store

  - wine-and-liquor
- mall
- department-store
- food-drink
- bookshop
- pharmacy
- electronics-shop
- hardware-house-garden-shop
- clothing-accessories-shop
- sport-outdoor-shop
- shop

business-services:

- atm-bank-exchange
- police-emergency

  - ambulance-services
  - fire-department
  - police-station
- post-office
- tourist-information
- petrol-station
- car-rental
- car-dealer-repair
- travel-agency
- communication-media
- business-industry
- service

facilities:

- hospital-health-care-facility

  - hospital
- government-community-facility
- education-facility
- library
- fair-convention-facility
- parking-facility
- toilet-rest-area
- sports-facility-venue
- facility

leisure-outdoor:

- recreation
- amusement-holiday-park

  - zoo

administrative-areas-buildings:

- administrative-region
- city-town-village
- outdoor-area-complex
- building
- street-square
- postal-area

natural-geographical:

- body-of-water
- mountain-hill
- undersea-feature
- forest-heath-vegetation