# Nokia HERE maps: How to get the MCZoom and MCPan components?

Tags: maps

[image]

I want the MCZoom and MCPan components shown in the HERE maps.(Ref picture)

http://here.com/51.506430,-0.127190,13,0,0,normal.day/map=12.966980,77.587290,13,0,0,normal.day

I have tried out all the components listed in the [documentation](http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.0/symbols/nokia.maps.map.component.html), but none of them renders the MCZoom and MCPan.

If its not something available for public to use, how do I create a component like this?

Comment: [here.com](http://here.com) doesn't just use the `MapComponents` from the [HERE Maps API for JavaScript](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis). The  `MCZoom` and `MCPan` are **custom** map components and not available by default. The best way forward here is to write your own `MapComponent` and inject an extra `<div>` element into the DOM - look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086514/is-it-possible-to-have-the-4-zoom-level-feature-with-ie9-and-ie10%) to see how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I guessed they were custom, I wrote my own Pan and ZoomBar. Its working very similar to MCPan and MCZoom of here.com, It was easy and fun to write. Thanks for your response.